# creating metadata template or add field to existing template with box api

Tags: api, metadata, box-api, box

Is there api call where User can append value on to pre existing metadata template

for example lets say I have metadata template called author and has dropdown of [bob, bill, mary , mark] but i want to push "dan" to the dropdown so the dropdown will be [bob, bill, mary , mark , dan]

OR

Is there a api call that allows for creating new metadata template?

I have looked for documents but most of them were creating metadata on to file with the existing template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metadata template creation and editing is only done through the Admin Console in the Web App at this time. The API only supports working with the values within the templates, not the keys.

Comment: thank you very much! I ended up contacting the metadata box email they said the api for creating template is coming soon, just have to wait