# Add field to metadata template with box sdk

Tags: api, sdk, box-api, box, boxapiv2

In reference of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34159403/creating-metadata-template-or-add-field-to-existing-template-with-box-api/35744656)

I've read [this blog entry](https://www.box.com/blog/metadata-templates-management-content-API/), but I can't see any funcionality to set metadata template in the sdk. 
Related to work with custom template paremeters I only know search functinality with BoxMetadataFilterRequest object in the SearchAsync method.

There is any news about this functionality to set or recover with the sdk (https://github.com/box/box-windows-sdk-v2)? Or only with Restsharp (or similar) messages I can use this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this functionality is not supported through the Windows SDK.

As you mentioned, you would have to call the metadata endpoints directly using a REST client like Restsharp.

Here is the documentation for the relevant Box Content API endpoints:

1. [Create Metadata endpoint](https://box-content.readme.io/reference#create-metadata)
2. [Update Metadata endpoint](https://box-content.readme.io/reference#update-metadata)